# Split the string using array of delimiters in r

Tags: regex, r

I am new to R. I have to split a sentence based on phrase delimiters. we can use strsplit for splitting the string based on one delimiter. I want to split the string based on number of delimiters such as [, . : ; ]. How can I do it in one step. Is there any regular expression applicable for this?

For example:

```
my_string = "This is a sentence.  This is a question, right?  Yes!  It is."
```

expected output :

```
"This is a sentence", "This is a question", "right", "yes", "It is"
```

Comment: can you share some sample string and the expected output?

Comment: Could you show us some example and code?

Comment: Using the built-in character sets might be helpful: `strsplit(my_string, "[[:punct:]](\\s+|$)")` , though admittedly this isn't transferable to all contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
strsplit("This is a sentence. This is a question, right? Yes! It is.", "\\.|,|\\?|!")
#[[1]]
#[1] "This is a sentence"  " This is a question" " right"             
#[4] " Yes"                " It is"
```

To get rid of those extra spaces, you could do this:

```
strsplit("This is a sentence. This is a question, right? Yes! It is.",
         "\\. *|, |\\? *|! *")
#[[1]]
#[1] "This is a sentence" "This is a question" "right"             
#[4] "Yes"                "It is"
```

As thelatemail pointed out, this is even simpler:

```
strsplit("This is a sentence. This is a question, right? Yes! It is.",
     "[,.:;?!]\\s*")  # \\s* represents a space character appearing 0 or more times
```

You need to escape certain characters that are otherwise interpreted as metacharacters.  That's why you see the `\\` in front of the `.` and the `?`.  The `|` is a sort of "or".

Comment: `strsplit(my_string, "[,.:;?!](\\s+|$)")` might be simpler than dealing with all the escaping etc.

Comment: @thelatemail Good call, I added your suggestion, except with the `*` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this pattern to get your output

```
        string input = @"This is a sentence. This is a question, right? Yes! It is.";
        string pattern = @"[, . : ; ]";

        foreach (string result in Regex.Split(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", result);
        }
```

please see the console whether you are getting the correct result.

Comment: You should escape your `.`, add `!`, and remove the spaces from your pattern.

Comment: @Joseph You are aware that the question is in R and that not all regex implementations in C# are present in R and vice versa? Generally, you should answer questions in R if they are about R, in C# if they are about C#, in python if they are in python.

Comment: @ jerry sorry for the mistake, will take care this from now onwards